# ANOVA LMER Eta squared

Tags: r, lme4, anova

I used the lmer package to run mixed models, when I use the anova function to retrieve the anova results, everything works. However, when I try and calculate the eta squared, I consistently get the error below. Any ideas?

`Dyestuff` is a dataset available with the `lmerTest` package. I 
use package ‘lme4’ version 1.1-21. package ‘lmerTest’ version 3.1-0 and package ‘sjstats’ version 0.17.7

```
fm1 <- lmer(Yield ~ 1 + (1|Batch), Dyestuff)
am <- anova(fm1, test="F")
eta_sq(am, partial = FALSE, ci.lvl = NULL, n = 1000, method = c("dist", "quantile"))
```

> Error: Result 2 is not a length 1 atomic vector
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In tidy.anova(model) :
>         The following column names in ANOVA output were not recognized or transformed: NumDF, DenDF

Comment: This looks like it's from the `sjstats` package.  Can you please give us a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo()` (or at least the versions of `lme4`, `lmerTest`, `sjstats`) ?

Comment: Thanks Ben, sorry for the lack of transparency, package ‘lme4’ version 1.1-21. package ‘lmerTest’ version 3.1-0 and package ‘sjstats’ version 0.17.7. Let me try with Dyestuff, dataset. Any help would be very appreciated. I am panicking a bit. iIt is a last part of my thesis, and I have 100s of mixed method models that I need to include an effect size for.

Comment: what package do you use for eta_sq? try to use omaga squared if possible. sjstats has a package for estimating both omega and eta however I am not sure if it supports lmer

Comment: package ‘sjstats’ version 0.17.7 contains sjstats. Still, the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**

- it may be *theoretically* difficult to compute eta-squared for mixed models, see e.g. [this CV question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358927/compute-partial-eta2-for-all-fixed-effects-anovas-from-a-lme4-model) (it does suggest some ways of computing R^2 values for mixed models, which might satisfy your need for an effect size)
- practically speaking, the proximal problem seems to be that internally the eta-squared computation in `sjstats` expects that the `anova()` method will return a table containing a row corresponding to the residual variance. `?anova.lmerModLmerTest` returns a table with only rows corresponding to the fixed effect terms (not the residual variance).
- in any case you might expect to have trouble computing an eta-squared for a model with no non-trivial fixed effects (i.e. a fixed-effect intercept only) ...

---

This might be more appropriate for the [sjstats issues list](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjstats/issues) but I'll use this space to share what I've figured out so far.

- Fitting an intercept-only model gives a similar error even if it's just an `lm()` fit (which ought to work if anything does):

```
fm0 <- lm(Yield ~ 1 , Dyestuff)
am0 <- anova(fm0, test="F")
eta_sq(am0)
```

> Error: Result 2 must be a single double, not a double vector of length 0
>   Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

- However: fitting a non-trivial (more fixed effects than just the intercept) `lmer(Test)` model also fails:

```
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
am2 <- anova(fm2, test="F")
eta_sq(am2)
```

> Error: Result 2 must be a single double, not a double vector of length 0
>   Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In tidy.anova(model) :
>     The following column names in ANOVA output were not recognized or transformed: NumDF, DenDF

(From what I can tell the warning message is actually harmless.)

The proximal cause of this problem seems to be that the internal `sjstats:::aov_stat_summary()` function returns a table with only a single row, for the SSQ/MSQ/etc. due to `Days`; it should also have a row for the residual SSQ/MSQ/etc.

```
sjstats:::aov_stat_summary(am3)
##  term    sumsq   meansq NumDF    DenDF statistic      p.value
## 1 Days 30030.94 30030.94     1 16.99998  45.85296 3.263825e-06
```

The problem is that the number of terms is internally computed as (`nrow(aov.sum)-1`), which doesn't make sense here.

Compare this with what we get with a `1+Days` model using `lm()`:

```
fm3 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days , sleepstudy)
am3 <- anova(fm3, test="F")
sjstats:::aov_stat_summary(am3)
##        term  df    sumsq     meansq statistic      p.value
## 1      Days   1 162702.7 162702.652  71.46442 9.894096e-15
## 2 Residuals 178 405251.6   2276.694        NA           NA
```

Digging a little deeper, we can see that this is a direct consequence of the way the `anova()` results are reported for mixed models:

```
anova(fm2)
## Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
##      Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
## Days  30031   30031     1    17  45.853 3.264e-06 ***
```

Note there is no "residuals" row. In contrast:

```
anova(fm3)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## Response: Reaction
##            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
## Days        1 162703  162703  71.464 9.894e-15 ***
## Residuals 178 405252    2277
```

Comment: Indeed, I appreciate the time and effort you took to generate the answer. The wider point here is that LMM is not conducive to effect size, so I will need to reconsider my approach. We are reporting one co-efficient of the model, as a result using delta R2 or R2 would not represent the effect. I am pretty lost here...

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use the function anova_stats from sjstats package it works.

```
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
am2 <- anova_stats(fm2, test="F")
```

Comment: sorry, I mean: am2 <- anova_stats(fm2)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to correct it. Don't post corrections as comments but leave the error in your answer.